# GeoJSON drawing in dimensions

Tags: maps

I am looking for something like the well-known online GeoSJON editors, but something that takes dimensions as input.

So for instance, I want to draw a polygon on a map that is 8 meters in width and 6 meters in height (a podium, a tent,..).

Comment: do you know about [mymaps.google.com](https://www.google.com/maps/d/), you can measure shapes and draw lines

Comment: yes, you can measure after you draw, but you cannot say, "draw me a box that is exactly 8 meter width and 6 meter height".
I'm playing around with QGIS now to see if I can accomplish it there.

Comment: you can measure then draw

Comment: Sorry but no, it's unusable for that purpose.
For instance I need to draw a rectangle with 90° angles which is exactly 8.25m by 6.25m.
Google Maps snaps to whole meters + you cannot force a 90° angle.